# Toggling ngShow on an element though a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to make an directive that modifies whether ngShow or ngHide is on an element.

This is what I have so far. A simple directive that listens to a message on the root scope and modifies the element's display style.  While this does work, I would like to apply ngShow/ngHide to the element in the case if I was using ngAnimate to apply a fade out when the the element becomes hidden.

**HTML**

```
<div id='myElement' my-directive/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
require('angular')
    .module('app')
    .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

/* @ngInject */
function progressListener($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $rootScope.$on('loading', function() {
                element[0].style.display = '';
            });
            $rootScope.$on('complete', function() {
                element[0].style.display = 'none';
            });
        }
    };
}
```

How do you toggle ngShow/ngHide on an element from a directive?

Answer (score 1):

you must include that in your isolated scope

```
<div id='myElement' my-directive ng-show="show"/>
```

in your link

```
       scope: {
        show : false // set what must be default
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $rootScope.$on('loading', function() {
                scope.show = true;
            });
            $rootScope.$on('complete', function() {
                 scope.show = false;
            });
        }
```

Comment: Is this the best way to approach this situation?  My concern is the developer would need to know to add ngShow to the element to get this behavior.

Comment: As I see it, it's more an architecture problem. The directive is changing something that is not in its scope - `show` should be either passed into the directive explicitely using `=` or `ng-show` should be a part of the directive template, wrapped in the directive. Otherwise it will get more complicated. Probably should use `compile` instead of `link` to add `ng-show` dynamically?

Comment: I tried your code above and it throws an exception. "definition.match is not a function"  Do you need to bind the property somehow in scope using &/= ?

Comment: So I defaulted it by making it optional {  show  : '=?' }  But even when I do that and inspect the DOM, it still displays ng=show="show"